# Django: inclusion_tag with multiple arguments

Tags: django

I've written an inclusion tag to show album reviews with a number of (optional) arguments. Here's the tag:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('reviews/review_trail.html')
def review_trail(review, coverPosition='left', scoreMode='corner', showLargeHeadings=False, wordsToShow=30):
return {
    'r' : review, 
    coverPosition: coverPosition, 
    scoreMode: scoreMode, 
    showLargeHeadings: showLargeHeadings, 
    wordsToShow: wordsToShow 
}
```

I call the tag like this:

```
{% review_trail review=r coverPosition="right" %}
```

None of the arguments seem to get passed through to my HTML template except for the `reviews` / `r` value. If I log the arguments inside the inclusion tag, I see them passed through correctly, but when I output them in the `review_trail.html` they're all blank. Am I using the wrong syntax, or is it not possible to use multiple arguments this way? Using Django 1.4 and [the docs seem to suggest this is fine](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using single quotes for all the keys in your dictionary, so python is using the values of the variables for the names of the keys instead.

Change it to:

```
return {
    'r': review, 
    'coverPosition': coverPosition, 
    'scoreMode': scoreMode, 
    'showLargeHeadings': showLargeHeadings, 
    'wordsToShow': wordsToShow 
}
```

Comment: Of course -- I'm a fool. The first argument was wrapped in quotes so that's why it worked. How did I not notice this?! Thank you!